# Sunspot Solr not responding to Rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-solr

Running : `rake sunspot:reindex --trace`

Returned: `Don't know how to build task sunspot:reindex.`

Tried running `rake sunspot:solr:start --trace` and got the following output:

```
** Invoke sunspot:solr:start (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute sunspot:solr:start
```

Sunspot 2.0.0 | Solr 1.0.9 | rails 2.3.5 | MacOS X

Comment: Are you running this code in windows environment or linux environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine whats going on here is the gem did not properly reinstall. Also it when working with old apps, you need to make sure that you update your system gems to the right version.

Start from scratch and do the following :

```
rvm gemset delete your_gemset
cd .
gem update --system 0.0.0 # Whatever version you know worked with the app you are using.
rake gems:install
```

`rake gems:install` is very flaky and is essentially why it was replaced with Bundler. Assuming your gems did not install all the way, try to manually install what didn't work :

```
gem install sunspot_solr
```

Then finally try the command :

```
rake sunspot:solr:start
```

You should have an active PID start that you can reveal by typing :

```
ps aux | grep solr
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running sunspot in a windows environement, then rake sunspot:solr:start will not work.

First you have to change in your C:\Ruby187\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\gems\sunspot-1.2.1\lib\sunspot\server.rb

comment the line

```
exec(Escape.shell_command(command))
```

and add the following line

```
exec(Escape.shell_command(command).gsub("'",'"'))
```

Then try using rake sunspot:solr:run

This is applicable only for your windows environment

Comment: I'm attempting to run this code in a linux environment (OS X 10.7.5). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did u run rake sunspot:install . If this is done then, you have to add a rake file inside your lib

Comment: That appears to be whats *not* working. It seems the rakefiles don't transfer over. Maybe because its an old sunspot version?